# Setting up dynamic custom domains on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, dns

I've got a simple Ruby on Rails applications where people can create events. The app is currently hosted on Heroku.

I'd like users to set a custom domain and the app would automatically do the DNS redirecting.

**An example.**
My website => mywebsite.com
Event Page => mywebsite.com/events/awesome-event
User sets a custom domain => userdomain.com/event-1

When people visit userdomain.com/event-1 they actually see mywebsite.com/events/awesome-event.

How do I do that automatically, so that I don't have to change manually DNS settings (at least on my end) but the custom domain is just stored on the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you could use heroku gems to achieve this.

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

with this gem you're able to manage your domain like this example

Domains

heroku.delete_domain(APP, 'example.com')   # remove the 'example.com' domain from the APP app
heroku.get_domains(APP)                    # list configured domains for the APP app
heroku.post_domain(APP, 'example.com')     # add 'example.com' domain to the APP app

Check this article about Custom Domains on heroku dev site.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: Hey Tanguy, thanks but this doesn't solve my problem. In fact I can use custom domains for the entire app and not for specific urls...

Comment: @ManuelFrigerio did you ever figure this out?